# Version control in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I apologize if this may be basic, but I spent over an hour trying to figure out where I can access my code from the previously deployed version in Apps Script. I can see my deployment and can access the link to teach deployed version, but I actually need the source of my 2 files.

Does it even exist? What am I missing?

Comment: After the script editor was updated, unfortunately, in the current stage, the older deployed script cannot be directly retrieved from the script editor. But, when "Method: projects.getContent" of Google Apps Script API is used, this can be achieved. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent) But, if this was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: You can also save all of the functions in  ascii text files using the api which make it very easy to access each versions code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the solution was provided by @Tanaike and @Cooper in the comments section.

The new Google Apps Script editor does not have a built-in feature to restore old versions of a script. To restore an old version of a script, you will need to use the Google Apps Script API or a third-party tool. There are several tools available that can help you with this, such as CLASP and Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant.

CLASP is a command-line tool that is a good option for small projects, while Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant requires a third-party Git service like GitHub or Bitbucket. If you are working on a large project, it is a good idea to use a version control system like Git to track changes to your script. This will make it easier to revert to an old version if necessary.

I also found this request to add this feature back [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236721237). You can vote for this request, so it can be added later on.

**Reference:**

- [Command Line Interface using clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)
- [Managing Versions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-versions)
- [Apps Script Method: projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent)
- [Apps Script Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)
- [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo)

### Update:

I made some sample codes, with both options, the one from @Tanaike to push the version to Apps Script and the one from @Cooper to download the information on a `TXT file`.

*Note: I made the sample in Python, since it's easier for me, but you can use any programming language*

*Note 2: You will need to create a project in [GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/), enable the `Apps Script API` in the project & under [User settings](https://script.google.com/home/usersettings), create a credentials file for desktop application. You can see the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python).*

**1. Push the version to a current Apps Script:**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects']



SAMPLE_MANIFEST = '''
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "exceptionLogging": "CLOUD"
}
'''.strip()


def main():

    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=creds)


        # the ID of the Apps script project where you need to get the version.
        # https://script.google.com/home/projects/editor_script-ID/edit 

        script_ID= 'editor_script-ID'

        
        response = service.projects()\
            .getContent(scriptId=script_ID, versionNumber=1, fields='*')\
                .execute()
        
        # Gets the code from the script. 

        source_value = response.get('files')[1]['source']

        # creates the body that will be push to Apps Script

        Request_body = {
            "files": [
                {
                    'source': source_value,
                    'name': 'test',
                    'type': 'SERVER_JS'
                    
                },
                {
                    'name': 'appsscript',
                    'type': 'JSON',
                    'source': SAMPLE_MANIFEST
                }
            ]
        }

        # You can push the code to the same Apps Script or a new one
        # if you want to push it to a new one, create a new variable for the scriptId
        request =  service.projects()\
            .updateContent(scriptId=script_ID, body = Request_body)\
                .execute()


    except errors.HttpError as error:
        # The API encountered a problem.
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2. **To push the version information to a backup file.**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects']


def main():

    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # the ID of the Apps script project where you need to get the version.
        # https://script.google.com/home/projects/editor_script-ID/edit 

        script_ID = 'editor_script-ID'

        # The version that you want to download

        version = 3

        
        response = service.projects()\
            .getContent(scriptId=script_ID, versionNumber=version, fields='*')\
                .execute()

        source_value = response.get('files')[1]['source']

        # I create a TXT file called "backup.txt" in the same filder as the code
        # The 'a' parameter will Opens a file for appending
        # and creates the file if it does not exist

        file = open('backup.txt', 'a')

        file.write('Version ' + str(version) + '\n\n'+ source_value + '\n\n')

        file.close


        
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        # The API encountered a problem.
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```